# Как удалить пробелы перед конкретным символом?

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle

Есть запрос следующего типа:

```
select '107 539250888 -539251910;107 539255001-539259995; 107 539260001 -539269995' from dual;
```

Нужно убрать пробелы которые идут перед знаком "-". Т.е. должно получится:

```
'107 539250888-539251910;107 539255001-539259995; 107 539260001-539269995'
```

Пытался сделать через regexp_replace, но пока не разобрался как он работает.

Comment: А что конкретно вы пробовали через regexp_replace? Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос

Comment: Кстати, почему именно регулярка? Может, сойдёт `REPLACE('107...', ' -', '-')`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew да и регулярка выглядела бы абсолютно так же, один в один.

Comment: @AlexKrass Возможно, всё зависит от конкретных требований, которых, к сожалению, в вопросе нет.

Comment: Заменить регуляркой  `' +-'` на `'-'`. А если пробел строго один, так и вовсе тупо подстроку ` -'` на `'-'`.

Comment: @Akina А если там ещё и знаки табуляции? Или \xA0?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Человек пишет "пробел". Табуляции и прочее - немного иначе называются.

Comment: Всем спасибо! Действительно можно было и просто с replace сделать (REPLACE('107...', ' -', '-')), не сообразил.

Answer (score 1):

Побробуйте так ([пример](https://sqltest.net/#577523)):

```html
WITH strings AS (   
  SELECT '107 539250888 -539251910;107 539255001-539259995; 107 539260001 -539269995' s from DUAL
)   
  SELECT s "STRING", REGEXP_REPLACE(s, '\s-', '-') "MODIFIED_STRING"  
  FROM   strings
```